# TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, parse-platform

I'm creating a service for returning coordinates of a location. But I need some way to return a value.

```
angular.module('google.maps', [])
.factory('geocode', ['$http', 'GOOGLE_MAPS_CREDENTIALS', function ($http,GOOGLE_MAPS_CREDENTIALS) {
    return {
        getCoords: function(addr1, zip) {
            $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
                +encodeURIComponent(addr1+','+zip)+'&sensor=false'
                +'&key='+GOOGLE_MAPS_CREDENTIALS.API_KEY);
        }
    }
}])
.value('GOOGLE_MAPS_CREDENTIALS', { API_KEY: '_____________' });
```

After this, I have a controller call this function as such:

```
.controller('AddrNewCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$stateParams','geocode','$rootScope','Address',
    function($scope, $state, $stateParams, geocode, $rootScope, Address) {
    $scope.address = {
        userId: {"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":$rootScope.user.id}
    };
    $scope.create = function() {
        geocode.getCoords($scope.address.address1, $scope.address.zipCode)
        .success(function(data) { // <-- this is where the console error is.
            var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            $scope.address.location = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude:lat,longitude:lng});
        });
        Address.create($scope.address)
        .success(function(data) { $state.go('tabs.address-list'); });
    };
}])
```

The problem is that when I call success, I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

There is little difference between how I implement this service versus any other service and when I `console.log` the data results in my `$http.get()` function, I get all the values I'm expecting when I invoke the function in the controller.

I'm looking for one of two answers:

1. Why is the `success` callback returning an error?
2. How can I simply return the a Coordinates object when I invoke my `geocode` service?

Comment: It's not the "success" callback itself that's the subject of the error. The error means that the `getCoords()` call is not returning anything.

Comment: you are not returning a promise on getCoords, you should have `return $http.get`

Comment: Wow, thank you. That resolved it @Pointy , feel free to put that in an answer and I'll give you creds for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have

```
 getCoords: function(addr1, zip) {
         return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
            +encodeURIComponent(addr1+','+zip)+'&sensor=false'
            +'&key='+GOOGLE_MAPS_CREDENTIALS.API_KEY);
    }
```